# expo-location not working in ios and not showing location permission in app settings

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to get the current location in IOS 14, but I am getting no response and when I check in expo
settings it's not showing location permission there. I have checked in both simulators and physical devices.

Hook Code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as Location from "expo-location";

export default useLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  const getLocation = async () => {
    try {
      const { granted } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (!granted) return;
      const {
        coords: { latitude, longitude },
      } = await Location.getLastKnownPositionAsync();
      setLocation({ latitude, longitude });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
  }, []);

  return location;
};
```

Response

```
undefined
```

Comment: Just had this problem too. Code with Mosh? I couldn't get that method working, but the Location.getCurrentPositionAsync() method seemed to work.

Comment: Funny thing I've had the same problem too. Feels good to know nothing is wrong with my code.

Comment: this problem has been solved for me, I am using Location.getCurrentPositionAsync and I have uninstalled the app and then restarted my physical device and then installed it again.It works :)

Answer (score 2):

The [docs says](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationgetlastknownpositionasyncoptions) `Location.getLastKnownPositionAsync()` might return null:

> Returns a promise resolving to an object of type LocationObject or
> null if it's not available or doesn't match given requirements such as
> maximum age or required accuracy.

so you should do something like:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as Location from "expo-location";

export default useLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  const getLocation = async () => {
    try {
      const { granted } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (!granted) return;
      const last = await Location.getLastKnownPositionAsync();
      if (last) setLocation(last);
      else {
        const current = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
        setLocation(current);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
  }, []);

  return location;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use requestForegroundPermissionAsync() instead of requestPermissionAsync. and the problem is solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`requestPermissionsAsync` has been deprecated I believe since SDK:42.

```
import { requestForegroundPermissionsAsync } from 'expo-location';
```

then

```
const { granted } = await requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
```